# How can a Hash Set incur collision?

Tags: java, hashset

If a hash set contains only  one instance of any distinct element(s), how might collision occur at this case?

And how could load factor be an issue since there is only one of any given element?

While this is homework, it is not for me. I am tutoring someone, and I need to know how to explain it to them.

Answer (score 4):

Let's assume you have a HashSet of Integers, and your Hash Function is mod 4. The integers 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, etc. will all colide, if you try to insert them. (mod 4 is a terrible hash function, but it illustrates the concept)

Assuming a proper function,  the load factor is correlated to the chance of having a collision; please note that I say correlated and not equal because it depends on the strategy you use to handle collisions. In general, a high load factor increases the possibility of collisions. Assuming that you have 4 slots and you use mod 4 as the hash function, when the load factor is 0 (empty table), you won't have a collision. When you have one element, the probability of a collision is .25, which obviously degrades the performance, since you have to solve the collision.

Now, assuming that you use linear probing (i.e. on collision, use the next entry available), once you reach 3 entries in the table, you have a .75 probability of a collision, and if you have a collision, in the best case you will go to the next entry, but in the worst, you will have to go through the 3 entries, so the collision means that instead of a direct access, you need in average a linear search with an average of 2 items.

Of course, you have better strategies to handle collisions, and generally, in non-pathological cases, a load of .7 is acceptable, but after that collisions shoot up and performance degrades.

Answer (score 1):

The general idea behind a "hash table" (which a "hash set" is a variety of) is that you have a number of objects containing "key" values (eg, character strings) that you want to put into some sort of container and then be able to find individual objects by their "key" values easily, without having to examine every item in the container.

One could, eg, put the values into a sorted array and then do a binary search to find a value, but maintaining a sorted array is expensive if there are lots of updates.

So the key values are "hashed".  One might, for instance, add together all of the ASCII values of the characters to create a single number which is the "hash" of the character string.  (There are better hash computation algorithms, but the precise algorithm doesn't matter, and this is an easy one to explain.)

When you do this you'll get a number that, for a ten-character string, will be in the range from maybe 600 to 1280.  Now, if you divide that by, say, 500 and take the remainder, you'll have a value between 0 and 499.  (Note that the string doesn't have to be ten characters -- longer strings will add to larger values, but when you divide and take the remainder you still end up with a number between 0 and 499.)

Now create an array of 500 entries, and each time you get a new object, calculate its hash as described above and use that value to index into the array.  Place the new object into the array entry that corresponds to that index.

But (especially with the naive hash algorithm above) you could have two different strings with the same hash.  Eg, "ABC" and "CBA" would have the same hash, and would end up going into the same slot in the array.

To handle this "collision" there are several strategies, but the most common is to create a linked list off the array entry and put the various "hash synonyms" into that list.

You'd generally try to have the array large enough (and have a better hash calculation algorithm) to minimize such collisions, but, using the hash scheme, there's no way to absolutely prevent collisions.

Note that the multiple entries in a synonym list are not identical -- they have different key values -- but they have the same hash value.